# How to escape function argument which has a default value in PHP?

Tags: php, function, arguments

I need to know how can I escape the arguments which has default values in PHP?
Imagine my function is:

```php
function avg($a = 1 , $b = 2) {
   return $a+$b;
}
```

and I want to call it in these forms:

```php
avg(3,4); // Correct Result: 7
avg(2); // Expected result: 4
avg(,5) // Expected result: 6
```

How can I do the function calls above in a correct way?

Comment: Why not use an `array` instead of multiple arguments?

Comment: You can't leave a parameter out, and PHP does not have named parameters. For your case, pass along `NULL` or `0` in the final case, and you get your expected result. Or, alter it to use an array instead.

Comment: pass `null` in the last case as the first argument

Comment: Using an `array` or `NULL` and `0` instead here works well, but it is just a sample function with a simple action. In a complex code, I think I should have that arguments in a normal way. But it seems there is not such mechanism in PHP normally.

Comment: You can't leave out arguments *up until* the last value you specify, because PHP doesn't have named parameters like some other languages do. If you got a more complex function, consider using the splat-operator or an array.

Answer (score 0):

But you can Do this,

```
function avg(...$args)
{
    list($a, $b) = $args + [1, 2];
    $a           = !empty($a) ? $a : 1;
    return $a + $b;
}
print_r(avg(3, 4)); // Correct Result: 7
print_r(avg(2)); // Expected result: 4
print_r(avg(null, 5)); // Expected result: 6
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9021469bea4f47cde61d93bbc97b286f9c95141).

It's not possible to skip arguments you did that way. You can achieve that only if they are at the end of the parameter's list.

There has been already many proposals sent in this regards but sadly rejected from there end.

You can see those [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that in this way you can solved issue.

[Using non-scalar types as default values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

```
function avg($a = null,$b =null) {

    $a = is_null($a) ? 1 : $a;
    $b = is_null($b) ? 2 : $b;

   return $a+$b;
}


echo avg(3,4); // Correct Result: 7

echo avg(2,null); // Expected result: 4

echo avg(null,5); // Expected result: 6
```